# Why is sysconf() so slow when called multiple times

Tags: c, unix

I need the `PAGESIZE` value each time my function is called, it's looks like caching system call `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` in a function static variable is much faster than calling it every time.

man page says:

> The values obtained from these functions are system configuration constants. They do not change during the lifetime of a process.

Then, why successive calls to sysconf are so slow if value does not change ?

Here is the code I used to test:

```
#include <unistd.h>
long a()
{
  return sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
}
long b()
{
  static long n;
  if (!n)
    n = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
  return n;
}
int main()
{
  for (int i = 800000000; i > 0; --i)
    a();
  return 0;
}
```

Result are: 4,8s for a() *vs* 1,7s for b(). It is even worse with `-O2`.

Comment: sys calls are not free - actually any call to nontrivial function will have significant impact in this case (800 mln calls) - do value caching on your side

Comment: @kiwixz It's probably implemented in some trivial fashion without caching. Given that, `sysconf` requests for pagesize are actually pretty cheap, compared to requests for other properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599074/system-calls-overhead/41783404#41783404. Pagesize is made available through the auxiliary vector on linux which makes obtaining it actually very cheap compared to other system calls.

Comment: Try `getpagesize()`?

Comment: @DYZ man page says it's legacy and not really portable, so I guess I should not :(

Comment: For `b()` it *should* take 0s, since the compiler should hoist the conditional out as a loop termination condition and break after the first iteration.