# Measure overhead without pthread in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads, userspace

I would like to share a test question I met recently and discuss about it:

> Write a C program that roughly measures the overhead of a context switch >between the kernel and userspace on a UNIX/Linux system (without using the >pthread API). Please indicate the assumptions your rough estimation is based >on.

I would like to discuss with more advanced C programmers the different options of this problematic.

I have limited knowledge in C programming and I documented myself to provide an acceptable answer:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/measuring-context-switching-and-memory-overheads-for-linux-threads/

https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_measure_thread_creation_and_destruction

https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/master/2018/threadoverhead/thread-pipe-msgpersec.c

I realized quickly, despite of my limited knowledge, the ambiguity of the question. Indeed, the question doesn't stipulate if an answer should be given in unit of time or memory.

I personally chose to develop my reasoning measuring time with the library time.h and a very simple snippet. Result should be divided by 1 000 000.

Does my answer make sense or am I completely missing the point ?

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    clock_t begin=clock();

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        printf("%d",i);
    }
    clock_t end=clock();
    printf("Time taken:%lf",(double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Comment: The "test question" is using incorrect terminology. The switch between kernel mode and user mode isn't technically called a context switch. It's called a mode switch. You can measure the overhead of a mode switch by benchmarking very minimal system calls. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599074/system-calls-overhead/41783404

Comment: What if your loop gets interrupted by another unrelated process? You risk taking into account the time spent into this other process, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try different approach.

As it was stated, you are trying to measure

> overhead of a context switch >between the kernel and userspace

Context switch from user to kernel is done via `syscall`. For sure printf underneath uses `write` syscall, but this syscall is too heavy to get reliable estimation. To improve this estimation you should answer to the question - what is the fastest syscall in linux? And the answer is - [syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) with invalid parameter.

P.S.
Don't forget about measurement accuracy. Also you should divide your result by 2 because syscall is a round-trip.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly enough, the answer I provided above was accepted as correct in this test.

However to optimize the accuracy, we should rule out the "printf" method and go for either a syscall with invalid parameter as mentioned by Alex Hoppus or an empty method.

At the end, result should divided by 2 as mentioned by Alex Hoppus.