# Why does strace ignore some syscalls (randomly) depending on environment/kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, strace, vdso

If I compile the following program:

```cpp
$ cat main.cpp && g++ main.cpp
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    struct timespec ts;
    return clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
}
```

and then run it under `strace` in "standard" Kubuntu, I get this:

```
strace -tt --trace=clock_gettime ./a.out
17:58:40.395200 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

As you can see, *there is no* `clock_gettime` (full `strace` output is [here](https://gist.github.com/DimanNe/e9634a1ed74747a01c926a4f515f1940)).

On the other hand, if I run the same app in my custom built linux kernel under `qemu`, I get the following output:

```
strace -tt --trace=clock_gettime ./a.out
18:00:53.082115 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=101481, tv_nsec=107976517}) = 0
18:00:53.082331 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Which is more expected - *there is* `clock_gettime`.

##### **So, my questions are**:

- Why does `strace` ignore/omit `clock_gettime` if I run it in Kubuntu?
- Why `strace`'s behaviour differs depending on environment/kernel?

Comment: Just an idea: there is not system call in the first example. man pages tell that CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE will use vdso, but possibly a later glibc may be able to optimize out also your function not to call kernel (with syscall). Such timing functions may be used very often by GUI, and so any optimization is noticeable

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Will you be able to turn this "CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE will use vdso, but possibly a later glibc may be able to optimize out also your function not to call kernel (with syscall)" into an answer? :) Essentially, the question is when a syscall is not a "proper" syscall, and what it depend on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to the first question

From [vdso man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)

strace(1), seccomp(2), and the vDSO

When tracing systems calls with strace(1), symbols (system calls) that are exported by the vDSO **will not appear in the trace output**.  Those system calls will likewise not be visible to seccomp(2) filters.

#### [Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553845/should-i-be-seeing-non-vdso-clock-gettime-syscalls-on-x86-64-using-hpet) to the second question:

In the vDSO, clock_gettimeofday and related functions are reliant on specific clock modes; see __arch_get_hw_counter.

**If the clock mode is VCLOCK_TSC, the time is read without a syscall**, using RDTSC; if it’s VCLOCK_PVCLOCK or VCLOCK_HVCLOCK, it’s read from a specific page to retrieve the information from the hypervisor. **HPET doesn’t declare a clock mode, so it ends up with the default VCLOCK_NONE, and the vDSO issues a system call to retrieve the time**.

And indeed:

In the default kernel (from Kubuntu):

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
tsc hpet acpi_pm
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
tsc
```

Custom built kernel:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
hpet
```

---

[More info](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Timers/linux-timers-6.html) about various clock sources. In particular:

> The documentation of Red Hat MRG version 2 states that TSC is the preferred clock source due to its much lower overhead, but it uses HPET as a fallback. A benchmark in that environment for 10 million event counts found that TSC took about 0.6 seconds, HPET took slightly over 12 seconds, and ACPI Power Management Timer took around 24 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the fact that `clock_gettime()` is part of the optimized syscalls. Look at the vdso mechanism described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19942352/14393739).
Considering `clock_gettime()`, on some architecture (e.g. Linux on ARM v7 32 bits), only a subset of the available clock identifiers are supported in the VDSO implementation. For the others, there is a fallback into the actual system call. Here is the source code of the VDSO implementation of `clock_gettime()` in the Linux kernel for the ARM v7 (file *arch/arm/vdso/vgettimeofday.c* in the source tree):

```c
notrace int __vdso_clock_gettime(clockid_t clkid, struct timespec *ts)
{
      struct vdso_data *vdata;
      int ret = -1;

      vdata = __get_datapage();

      switch (clkid) {
      case CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE:
            ret = do_realtime_coarse(ts, vdata);
            break;
      case CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE:
            ret = do_monotonic_coarse(ts, vdata);
            break;
      case CLOCK_REALTIME:
            ret = do_realtime(ts, vdata);
            break;
      case CLOCK_MONOTONIC:
            ret = do_monotonic(ts, vdata);
            break;
      default:
            break;
      }

      if (ret)
            ret = clock_gettime_fallback(clkid, ts);

      return ret;
}
```

The above source code shows a `switch/case` with the supported clock identifiers and in the default case, there is a fallback to the actual system call.
On such architecture, spying a software like systemd which uses `clock_gettime()` with **CLOCK_MONOTONIC** and **CLOCK_BOOTTIME**, `strace` only shows the calls with the latter identifier as it is not part of the supported cases in VDSO mode.

Cf. this [link](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/systemd_vdso.html) for reference